# Cisco ip helper-address how exactly translation works?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

Can anyone explain how exactly works translation from broadcast to unicast? What is changed or modified in IP packet? Already I have read how it works and configured it properly for my network but still main question has left.

Example:
I want to create IP helper from whole subnet 192.168.1.0/24(R1) to 192.168.2.0/24(R2)
To manage this I have configured:

```
R1:
- ip forward-protocol 10,
- int vlan100
    ip addr 192.168.1.254
    ip helper-address 192.168.2.255

R2:
- access-list 200 permit udp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 eq 10
- int vlan200
    ip addr 192.168.2.254
    ip directed-broadcast 200
```

Now when I take a look on wireshark it looks like:
PCA sends packet to 192.168.2.255 with source 192.168.1.10 **and here is the question how that 192.168.2.255 is translated to unicast?**
At R2 it's source 192.168.1.10 and dest 255.255.255.255 with ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: You seem to be attempting to use two/three features: `ip helper-address`, `ip forward-protocol` and `ip directed-broadcast`, where the first two of these come with some default ports list they act upon, but these features are doing different things. What is the goal of this configuration?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

There's no translation or modification of a packet.

The router receive a broadcast packet that contains a DHCP request. Then it send a **new** unicast packet to the configured DHCP server requesting a lease on behalf of the host. Among other thing it contains the MAC address of the host.

The DHCP server send the response to the router. Then the router send an unicast packet to the originator (since it knows its mac address), and so on.

In human language it's something like:

- host: yell "Hello, I'm Joe, I need an IP address"
- router: ear Joe and send a call to DHCP "Joe need an IP address, can you give me one?"
- DHCP: respond to router "Sure, I can give Joe IP address A"
- router: respond to Joe "You can get IP address A, is it ok for you?"
  etc...

Comment: That is correct for the  DHCP relay feature of `ip helper-address`, but I think the OP  is trying to achieve/understand something else, what with udp/10 being in the mix.

Comment: Ok, but how we determine that new packet is unicast? If it's sitll addressed as broadcast x.x.x.255? I'm using other proto than DHCP but as I understand it works in similar way.

Comment: Just for reference DHCP relaying is defined to be the same as BOOTP relaying, as laid out in some detail of section 4 of RFC 1542 "Clarifications and Extensions for the Bootstrap Protocol".
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1542

Answer (score 1):

I'll base my answer on what I believe to have understood from your description, which is this:

- R1 has a directly a attached subnet with 192.168.1.254 ( I'll assume /24)
- R2 has a directly a attached subnet with 192.168.2.254 ( I'll assume /24)
- there is some form of connectivity between R1 and R2, distinct from these two subnets.
- adjacent to R1, there is a sender (192.168.1.10), broadcasting "something" to 192.168.1.255 or 255.255.255.255, with udp port 10.
- **Goal:** you want the sender's udp/10 broadcast to be picked up by R1, be forwarded towards R2, and be disseminated in R2's attached subnet as a broadcast.

Based on the config snippets you gave, this is what will be happening:

- PC1 at R1 broadcasts an udp/10 packet to 255.255.255.255 or 192.168.1.255 (src: 192.168.1.10, dst ...255)
- on R1, `interface vlan100`with `ip helper 192.168.2.255` will pick up that broadcast (because it's been enabled to work on udp/10, by virtue of `ip forward protocol 10`)
- **R1 will rewrite this into a unicast packet with destination address 192.168.2.255 and will send out that unicast**, according to its routing table.  The packet now has Src 192.168.1.10 and Dst 192.168.2.255. R1 has no knowlegde (and doesn't need it) if 192.168.2.255 happens to be a broadcast address in that remote subnet "somewhere else"
- R2 will receive this packet on its R1 facing interface (still with Src 192.168.1.10 and Dst 192.168.2.255)
- R2, by looking up the routing table (well, maybe CEF table) will decide that this packet needs to be forwarded out through `interface vlan 200`.
- R2 will detect that the destination address is the given subnet's broadcast address, will check for the presence of `ip directed broadcast [ACLofAllowedSourceIPs]` and check if 192.168.1.10 is in that ACL
- If checks succeed, **R2 will rewrite the packet's destination IP address to 255.255.255.255** (and Dst MAC to ff:ff:ff:ff) and send out that packet/frame through its `interface vlan200`. And there you are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's what I've already know :) Main point is that what you have bolded - **R1 will rewrite this into a unicast packet with destination address 192.168.2.255 and will send out that unicast** - and this is what I don't exactly understand... How am I suppose let's say in wireshark to determine that THIS packet is unicast not broadcast? What is the difference? Because it's still addressed to broadcast address...

Comment: Well, that's what `ip helper-address` does. It picks up an incoming broadcast (of certain types), rewrites the destination address to the configured helper-address, and forwards the packet according to the current state of its routing table. At this point, R1 has no idea that "somewhere else in the network", this unicast helper address might happen to be the broadcast address in the destination network (and it does not need to know - it's a unicast packet like any other). Only the last hop router (R2, in your case) can know if that address is actually a broadcast address.

Comment: If you looked at the packet on an intermediate link between R1 and R2, even at  the ingress interface of R2, you'd see SrcIP 192.168.1.10, DstIP 192.168.2.255, and _unicast_ Src/Dst MACs to match the given underlying L2/DataLink (might be PPP, HDLC, Ethernet, TokenRing...). At this point, you _can not_ know that this packet is supposed to become a broadcast beyond R2, nor that it had been a broadcast at R1.

Comment: So if I use ip helper-address command with broadcast addres let's say 192.168.2.255 how routers know that it should be forwarded not discarded as normal broadcast packet? Let's create a small modification and insert between R1-R2 another router  **R1-R3-R2**. To make it works we do not need to configure anything on R3, how that routers knows that it should forward that packet and not discard it? And to make it clear - PC1 when sends broadcast packet it sends it also to directed mac address not to broadcast one.

Comment: `how routers know that it should be forwarded not discarded as normal broadcast packet?` That's because none of the routers along  the path (except R2, eventually) have any clue that 192.168.2.255 is actually a broadcast address of a network. Eventually, only R2 can tell, because it is (in a well-addressed network) the only router that has the given subnet locally attached. To any other router, 192.168.2.255 is just "a destination address" - they don't know. They cannot even know if the L2 medium "somewhere over there" is even broadcast cabable.

Comment: Well I'm asking it, because it looks like when the broadcast address is 192.168.2.255 and I'll use it as ip helper-address to reach whole subnet, nothing has changed with ip-helper command, packet is still same as before (only mac as it's L2 is changed).

Comment: `the only router that has the given subnet locally attached` and now u messed my head :) so let's look from the other side. 192.168.2.255 is connected to R2, and R1 do not have subnet like this. In this case if I understand it correctly, R1 should forward it without ip helper-address, because it has no information about that subnet and do not recognize it as broadcast address?

Comment: If R1 were to *receive* a packet with Dst 192.168.2.255, it would just forward it according to what the routing table says (in extenso: towards R2) - _without_ any `ip helper-address` config. That's the famous WakeOnLAN use case. The well-configured WoL server knows (by explicit configuration) the subnets (and the corresponding broadcast addresses) of its clients and unicast-sends to the broadcast address of these subnets. Only by virtue of `ip directed broadcast` on R2's *egress* interface into 192.168.2.0/24, the WoL packets become broadcasts in the destination network.

Comment: Thanks, that's all what I wanted to know. As you mentioned I was creating something like WoL - I used ip helper-address but I also had noticed that without it, it works too. To clarify this, so is it good practice to use in this case ip helper-address and ip forward protocol X to  limit protocols available to be forwarded? Or is it better to disable ip helper and create ACL?

Comment: WoL (often together with PXE) just needs two things: A) a well-configured WoL server, with a list of the broadcast addresses of the subnets where its clients are. B) `ip directed broadcast [ACLofAllowedSenders]` on the "last hop" router interfaces into the client subnets, use of this ACL highly recommended. Any other intermediate router does not need anything else. To them, WoL packets are just unicast.

Comment: Ok, but if we configure WoL server properly, what is recommended to be configured on **nearest hop** from it? `1) ip address-helper + ip forward protocol` or maybe `2) ACL for certain port numbers` ? Just for avoiding overheading or unexpected traffic?

Comment: PXE just needs `ip helper-address PXEServersIP` and possibly  `ip helper-address DHCPServerIP`  on the "first hop" router (from the client's perspective). Since `ip helper-address` covers a range of udp ports by default (including BOOTP/DHCP), it is recommended to _disable_ the unwanted forward-protocols by a set of `no ip forward-protocol ...` commands.

Comment: `Ok, but if we configure WoL server properly, what is recommended to be configured on nearest hop from it?`  Answer: Nothing is needed on the first hop. For WoL, only the _last hop_ router needs `ip directed-broadcast [ACLofAllowedSenders]`, and only on its _egress_ interfaces into the client subnet(s).